# Is there a way to make a single API call to determine traffic jam level in the direction of travel?

Tags: here-api

Is there way to make a single API call to Here-API to determine the level of traffic in the direction of travel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Detailed description of the API is given on developer.here.com

you can call the below API to see the jam factor :

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow/xml/8/134/86?app_id=XXXXi&app_code=YYYY

For more information kindly visit :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/request-constructing.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.